# Whether i need to use Ontology or database?

Tags: ontology

I have a set of football related keywords, a data set of positive sentiments words and negative sentiments words with me. My requirement is to combine these and search is social media to get some real time discussions and posts, and do some statistical analysis and reach some conclusions. This keywords and data sets are dynamically updating one. Now my question is

1. What is the best practice to handle the three sets of data? Using an Ontology structure or Well structured database?
2. Whether the data in the ontology is able to access from any programming languages? can i update or retrieve the data in Ontology using .NET or R or with any other programming language?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Representing the related keywords as an ontology is a good idea rather than storing in a database. 
SPARQL can be used to access and search the ontology to get related information
Your system will be semantically rich if its an ontology
If its a database, may be the access time may be improved but it will not be semantically rich

You may use apache jena which is a free Java API for creating an ontology.

Python also has many plugins for ontology generation.